# I wrote the code for -> check list is palindrome or not in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

But it does not work for 2 elements. Can someone check it out?

I created methods

reverseList for reversing elements

middleElement for finding mid of that linked list.

```java
            package com.Company;
            import java.math.BigInteger;
            import java.util.Objects;
            // This gfg21 class 
            class gfg21{
                private int size;
                gfg21(){
                    this.size = 0;
                }
            
                public class Node{
                    int data;
                    Node next;
            
                    Node(int data){
                        this.data = data;
                        this.next = null;
                        size++;
                    }
                }
                Node head;
    // addFirst for adding elements
                public Node addFirst(int data){
                    Node newNode = new Node(data);
                    if (head == null){
                        head = newNode;
                        return head;
                    }
                    newNode.next = head;
                    head = newNode;
                    return head;
                }
                public Node reverseList(Node head){
                    Node currentNode = head;
                    Node prevNode = null;
                    while (currentNode != null){
                        Node temp = currentNode.next;
                        currentNode.next = prevNode;
                        prevNode = currentNode;
                         currentNode = temp;
                    }
                    return prevNode;
                  
                }
            
                public Node middleElement(Node head){
                    if (head == null){
                        return null;
                    }
                    Node slowPtr = head;
                    Node fastPtr = head;
                    while (fastPtr != null && fastPtr.next != null){
                        slowPtr = slowPtr.next;
                        fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next;
                    }
                    return slowPtr;
                }
            
                public boolean palindromeList(Node head){
                    if (head == null){
                        return true;
                    }
                    Node mid = middleElement(head);
                    Node last = reverseList(mid.next);
                    Node currentNode = head;
                    while (last != null){
                        if (last.data != currentNode.data){
                            return false;
                        }
                        last = last.next;
                        currentNode = currentNode.next;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                public void printList(){
                    if (head == null){
                        System.out.println("List is empty");
                        return;
                    }
                    Node currentNode = head;
                    while (currentNode != null){
                        System.out.print(currentNode.data + " -> ");
                        currentNode = currentNode.next;
            
                    }
                    System.out.println("Null");
                }
            }
            public class gfg2 {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    
                    gfg21 palindrome = new gfg21();
                    palindrome.addFirst(2);
                    palindrome.addFirst(1);
                    palindrome.printList();
            
                    palindrome.palindromeList(palindrome.head);
                    if (palindrome.palindromeList(palindrome.head)){
                        System.out.println("Palindrome list");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Not Palindrome list");
                    }
            
                }
            }
```

Comment: What *exactly* "does not work"?

Comment: btw, if you just coded a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), both your life and code would be simpler.

Comment: Hey guys, the above code is not compatible with 2 elements. Just I want to know where I did a mistake?

Comment: Try debugging your code with the debugger in your IDE.